# Is there any conditional in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

> Maybe it will be possible to pass the English speaking interview in a few months if you will be watching movies with English subs every day and clarify the misunderstanding of English grammar.

Is there any conditional in this sentence? More specifically, is there an if-will exclusive in my example?

Comment: Yes. The word "if" introduces a conditional clause.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When someone says that "**if** something happens, **then** something else will happen," it is a conditional.

The sentence you gave is a little bit trickier, because it does not say "**then**" anywhere. However, you can easily give it one, and it will still make sense.

> "**If** you watch movies with English subs every day and clarify your misunderstandings of English grammar, **then** it will be possible to pass the English language exam."

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But is my example grammatical is incorrect? We have an argument about it.)

Comment: @NadiaKrasnova  it's grammatical, but (in my opinion) *"will be watching"* is awkward.  *"If you watch"* is better.